# what is advantage of multiple drawable?

Tags: android

most resources have pointed out that when we using (ldpi, mdpi,hdpi, xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi), the android doesn't need to rescale image and we won't have cpu overhead for rescaling image.

but i didn't got that point yet, suppose i have an icon image with all size that already mentioned (36px, 48px, 72px, 96px, 144px and 192px), well, in bellow code you see i use 40dp that it doesn't match any above sizes, so android would rescale the image again, then what is advantage if multiple drawable?

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android: src="@drawable/icon"
        />
```

Comment: When you say 40dp, you are talking about density independent pixels, so they scale according to device. When you have 1 high resolution image, it will take more computing power to scale it down to a low resolution phone

Comment: I think what he's saying is, even after converting DP -> PX none of the icon sizes line up, so some amount of scaling is necessary.  This is true.

Answer (score 0):

You'll often not have an image with an exact Pixel match for the DPs you describe in the layout -- like the case you describe above.  When this happens Android will still need to do some scaling.

The benefit isn't CPU savings, its Memory savings.
Scaling operations on large images can require a great deal of memory, especially if scaling from small to large, or large to small.

If you're starting with an image that is close and only need to scale a little, the memory cost is less significant.

If an image is w500px, h500px, that is 250000 pixels.  Even if that image is a jpg and compressed to be 10kb on the disk, scaling requires Android to convert to RGB or ARGB which is 3 or 4 bytes per pixel.

4 bytes x 250000 = 1M of memory.
500px on a device that is XXXHDPI is only about 1 inch on the screen.
So you can see how this can add up quickly.

EDIT: This might be useful https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what Aaron says, the benefit of providing these images is not about system resources, it is about how your app will look to users on different devices. By providing high-resolution copies of the same image, users on high-resolution devices will see crisp, clear images instead of upscaled fuzzy images.

Your question mentions specific pixel dimensions for an image. I assume these values are taken from https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

> - 36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
> - 48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
> - 72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
> - 96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
> - 144x144 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
> - 192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density

When you provide all of these different resolutions for your image, you are **not** providing different **physical sizes**. Of course 144x144 is three times larger than 48x48, but this 144x144 image will not appear three times larger when the user sees it on their device.

The system will only choose to display the 144x144 image when the user has a device with a high-resolution screen. This means the individual pixels in their display will be smaller, which means the 144x144 image will take up the same physical space as the 48x48 would on a lower-resolution screen.

In short: all of the images in this example are 48dp x 48dp.

Now, if you display this image in an `ImageView` that is 40dp x 40dp, the image will either be cropped or scaled down. But this has nothing to do with the extra images you've provided. Whether on a very low-resolution screen or a very high-resolution screen, the system will still be stuffing a 48x48 image into a 40x40 container.

### Update

Here's an example. I've used Android Studio's `New -> Image Asset` menu to create an image. You can see that AS generates multiple copies of the same image with different dimensions:

[image]

Next, I create two emulators:

- Nexus S (hdpi): http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_google_nexus_s-3620.php
- Nexus 5 (xxhdpi): http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_nexus_5-5705.php

And then I run an app that just displays my image on both of them:

You can see that the status bars, action bars, and the little android all appear the same size. But the Nexus S is displaying the hdpi image (48px x 48px) while the Nexus 5 is displaying the xxhdpi image (96px x 96px). Both look sharp!

[image]

Finally, I delete all copies of my image except for the mdpi one. Now both emulators use the mdpi image, but you can see that they still display at the same size. The image's intrinsic size is 32dp x 32dp, so even though both emulators are using a 32px x 32px image, both have to scale it up (the Nexus S has to scale it 1.5x and the Nexus 5 has to scale it 3x).

[image]

As you can see, the little android is the same *size*, but it **looks much worse**. This is why you provide copies of the same image at different resolutions: so that your images always appear crisp!

Comment: Downvote because i think you haven't read the question and Aron's answer well! and also for your mistake in your answer. if only advantage was what you said we could use just an image with High resolution (xxhdpi) and let android to downscale to desired size.

Comment: @programmer1 I'm not sure what you mean. If you only provide an xxhdpi image, the system *will* downscale it on mdpi devices. But of course the downscaled image won't look as good as one that was originally made for mdpi devices.

Comment: i can't get mean. Re-scaling is inevitable. it's rarely possible to use exactly same drawable size for our images in real projects. we are completely free to choose the width and height of the images widget and in drawable folder we don't have all image size from 1px.1px to 1000px.1000px to avoid rescaling. Additionally, I did not see a significant changes in downscaling. Do you have any referable reason for what you said? if i make mistake please explain more. thanks.

Comment: thanks for updating answer but our discussion is about downscaling not upscaling. please instead mdpi image, just keep xxxhdpi one and test again. you'll see that the result will appears crisp without providing multiple drawable resources.

Comment: @programmer1 that might be what _you_ are talking about, but it is not what the original question asks. Alex asked what the advantage of multiple drawables is, and my answer addresses that.

Comment: Additionally, even downscaling will cause problems on high-detail images. Original xxxhdpi image: http://i.imgur.com/aU4ukK9.png hdpi screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/MmA6NN6.png

Comment: @BenP. I disagree, the question is clearly concerned with performance as the OP mentions CPU overhead.  And to your point regarding scaling and image quality, like programmer1 said and I eluded to earlier, almost all images will be scaled so crispness is factored out.  The real benefit is performance.

Comment: I'm not really sure why people say "almost all images will be scaled". You are in control of your app; create image assets that are the size you want! If you're using e.g. standard icons from the material icon library, you should use them at their specified sizes. Across hundreds of screens and thousands of ImageViews I can't think of the last time I intentionally scaled an image in my apps.